# Enzyme hasClass returning false is wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following React component:

```js
const FeatureAccess = ({ value }) => {
  let liClass = `FeatureAccessList-item FeatureAccessList-item--${value}`

  return (
    <li class={liClass}>
      <label for={`user_member_permission_ids_${value}`}>
        <input
          name='user[member_permission_ids][]'
          id={`user_member_permission_ids_${value}`}
          value={value}
        />
      </label>
    </li>
  )
}
```

The idea is that the `li` element has 2 classes:

```
FeatureAccessList-item
FeatureAccessList-item--${value}
```

However my test is always failing, Enzyme is no asserting it correctly for some reason:

```js
// wrapper = mount(<FeatureAccess {...props} />)

it('should have the correct class depending on "value"', () => {
  const value = 'Spider-sense'
  wrapper.setProps({ value })

  // Expected: true, Received: false
  expect(wrapper.find('li').hasClass(`FeatureAccessList-item--${value}`)).toBe(true)
})
```

It doesn't make any sense because if I log the actual result of `wrapper.find('li')` this is what I get:

```
  console.log spec/javascripts/Users/components/FeatureAccess.spec.jsx:46

    <li class="FeatureAccessList-item FeatureAccessList-item--Spider-sense">
      <label for="user_member_permission_ids_Spider-sense">
        <input class="user_member_permission_ids " name="user[member_permission_ids][]" id="user_member_permission_ids_Spider-sense" value="Spider-sense" type="checkbox" checked={false} onChange={[Function: onChange]} />
      </label>
    </li>
```

The class is there! What's happening here?

I also tried with `` find(`.FeatureAccessList-item--${value}`).exist() `` and it also returns false...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `className` instead of `class`

https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

> Since JSX is closer to JavaScript than to HTML, React DOM uses
>   camelCase property naming convention instead of HTML attribute names.
>
> For example, class becomes className in JSX, and tabindex becomes
>   tabIndex.

Comment: That was it man, thanks.. too many hours in front of the screen I guess.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy can't do until 10 minutes after posting it ;)